# Python: Inheriting a class sets the generic type hinting

Tags: python, inheritance, generic-type-parameters

I have a `Car` with attribute `wheel`
I have 4 categories of cars:

- TravelStyle: what is the car purpose

  - Race: All of the attribute of child class of Race should be `RaceType`
  - Pleasure:

    - All of the attribute of child class of Pleasure should be `PleasureType`
    - All children class of Pleasure should have method `sing`

*Note*: There will always be only these 2 TravelStyles

- FruitStyle: What is the cars fruit

  - Strawberry: They have specific `strawberry` attribute
  - Bananas: They have specific `banana` attribute

*Note*: In the future, there WILL be the need to add new fruits, like `Cherry`.

From this I can only create these objects:

- RaceStrawberryCar: a Strawberry car with Race style
- PleasureStrawberryCar: a Strawberry car with Pleasure style
- RaceBananaCar: a Banana car with Race style
- PleasureBananaCar: a Banana car with Pleasure style

Here is a sample code of an exhaustive way to write these 4 classes:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass


class PleasureType:
    pass


class RaceType:
    pass


@dataclass
class RaceStrawberryCar:
    wheel: RaceType
    strawberry: RaceType


@dataclass
class PleasureStrawberryCar:
    wheel: PleasureType
    strawberry: PleasureType

    def sing(self, views: int) -> list:
        raise NotImplementedError


@dataclass
class RaceBananaCar:
    wheel: RaceType
    bananas: RaceType


@dataclass
class PleasureBananaCar:
    wheel: PleasureType
    bananas: PleasureType

    def sing(self, views: int) -> list:
        raise NotImplementedError
```

However, here there are few flaws:

- Code repetition
- Hard to extend: Every time we need to add a new fruit ( like Cherry ), we'll need to recreate 2 classes.

My question is therefore: do you have any idea of a design to make this class construction more consistent, and easily extendable ?
I set the requirements above.

For now, my first intent was the use of the generic types and inheritance. Here is the sample of code:

```py
from abc import ABC
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Generic, TypeVar


class PleasureType:
    pass


class RaceType:
    pass


T = TypeVar("T")


@dataclass
class Car(Generic[T], ABC):
    wheel: T


@dataclass
class RaceCar(Car[RaceType], ABC):
    pass


@dataclass
class PleasureCar(Car[PleasureType], ABC):
    def sing(self, views: int) -> list:
        raise NotImplementedError


@dataclass
class StrawberryCar(Car[T], ABC):
    strawberries: T


@dataclass
class RaceStrawberryCar(StrawberryCar[RaceType], RaceCar):
    pass


@dataclass
class PleasureStrawberryCar(StrawberryCar[PleasureType], PleasureCar):
    pass


@dataclass
class BananaCar(Car[T], ABC):
    bananas: T


@dataclass
class RaceBananaCar(BananaCar[RaceType], RaceCar):
    pass


@dataclass
class PleasureBananaCar(BananaCar[PleasureType], PleasureCar):
    pass
```

What I don't like about this approach, is that to set a car of `Race` type, we need to define it 2 times:

- Defining the generic type of the base `Fruit`car
- Defining the inheritance from a `Race` car

I.e. , in the statement `class PleasureBananaCar(BananaCar[PleasureType], PleasureCar):`, we define it 2 times:

- By setting the type of `BananaCar` to `PleasureType`
- By stating that the class inherits from `PleasureCar`

Doing this way, creating this class is totally acceptable:

```py
@dataclass
class HybridBananaCar(BananaCar[PleasureType], RaceCar):
    pass
```

And I don't want to be able to do that.

My first idea to overcome this, was to try to define the generic type when inheriting from a class, i.e.:

- If a class inherits from `RaceCar`, then the generic type is set to `RaceType`
- If a class inherits from `PleasureCar`, then the generic type is set to `PleasureType`

I tried this, but it obviously doesn't work:

```py
from abc import ABC
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Generic, TypeVar


class PleasureType:
    pass


class RaceType:
    pass


T = TypeVar("T")


@dataclass
class Car(Generic[T], ABC):
    wheel: T


@dataclass
class RaceCar(ABC):
    T = RaceType
    pass


@dataclass
class PleasureCar(ABC):
    T = PleasureType

    def sing(self, views: int) -> list:
        raise NotImplementedError


@dataclass
class StrawberryCar(Car[T], ABC):
    strawberries: list[T]


@dataclass
class RaceStrawberryCar(StrawberryCar, RaceCar):
    pass


@dataclass
class PleasureStrawberryCar(StrawberryCar, PleasureCar):
    pass


@dataclass
class BananaCar(Car[T], ABC):
    bananas: T


@dataclass
class RaceBananaCar(BananaCar, RaceCar):
    pass


@dataclass
class PleasureBananaCar(BananaCar, PleasureCar):
    pass
```

Any suggestion is welcomed. I repeat, I am not stuck with this class structure, any other suggestion for class structure that fulfills my requirements are welcome.

Comment: I feel like the reason why it's so hard to design a sensible structure for this is because of coupling 2 different attributes together - wouldn't it be possible to extract differences between Race and Pleasure fruits into a separate interface, that will be selected based on the car type?

Comment: I would like my Cars to be of type `Race` or `Pleasure`, for later use.
And the main difference is that `Race` car mean that all of the attribute of the car should be of type `RaceType`, and `Pleasure` car mean that all of the attribute of the car should be of type `PleasureType`.
Regardless of what exactly the attributes are ( can be `banana`, can be `wheel`, `strawberry`, even new ones like `door`, `engine` ... )

Comment: I got that, and that's imho quite problematic requirement, especially that **every** attribute needs to be of that type.

Comment: Yes that is the main painpoint.
I'm open to any suggestion. Also, if you think my design is not pythonic/goes against OOP principles, please tell me 